# PXSelector with composite Substitute Key

Tags: acumatica

I have SegmentID as identity column along with SegmentCD and Revision defiend with IsKey=True.

Now on Area page We have grid linked with AreaSegment DAC where user can select the Segment - for this we need to show
SegmentCD-Revision in the column instead of SegmentID
To achieve this we have created DisplaySegmentKey on Segment DAC that returns value SegementCd-Revision
and on AreaSegment  DAC we Designed
SegmentID with PXSelector with search and DescriptionField - DisplaySegmentKey
Everything works OK.

But on Import export where we use the value  system does not convert it to SegmentID and gives null value error for Segment field.

We also tried by making DisplaySegmentKey as DB field and setting its value on Field Updated of RevisionID on Segment Graph and instead of Description field used it as substitute key but still facing the same issue

Comment: It could help if you share code of your DAC, Views in the Area page graph and the Grid definition. Also an example of the file you're trying to import to see which columns are being used.
The field you use in a selector needs a way to map back to the ID. When you use a field that is key Acumatica can do it directly. If your SegmentCD and Revision fields are not generated automatically you could try making your DisplaySegmentKey DB field the key with IsKey=true instead of the other two.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, I would suggest you to set `SegmentID` as `SubstituteKey` for `DisplaySegmentKey` which will enable to get `SegmentID` from the `DisplaySegementKey` field.

Comment: Hi Vidhya,
SegmentID can not be used as a substitute key as the selector is for Substitute key and in that PXSelector to show user-friendly value Substitute key is used as DisplaySegmentID.

Comment: Hello @Shaj, can you please explain the reason for having `DisplaySegmentID` field, since `DisplaySegmentKey` is only for display and `SegmentID` is the key field right?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need this concatenated field. You can setup 2 different selectors for the SegmentId(Cd) and RevisionId taking the AMBOMItem as template

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<AMBomItem.bOMID,
        InnerJoin<AMBomItemBomAggregate,
            On<AMBomItem.bOMID, Equal<AMBomItemBomAggregate.bOMID>,
                And<AMBomItem.revisionID, Equal<AMBomItemBomAggregate.revisionID>>>>>))]
    public virtual string BOMID 

[PXSelector(typeof(Search<AMBomItem.revisionID,
        Where<AMBomItem.bOMID, Equal<Optional<AMBomItem.bOMID>>,
            Or<AMBomItem.bOMID, Equal<Current<AMBomItem.bOMID>>>>>),
        typeof(AMBomItem.revisionID),
       ...)]
    public virtual string RevisionID 

  [PXProjection(typeof(Select4<AMBomItem,
    Aggregate<
        GroupBy<AMBomItem.bOMID>>>), Persistent = false)]
public class AMBomItemBomAggregate : IBqlTable
```

For the selector of the SegmentId field, you can specify the SegmentCD as the SubstituteKey. The join with the 'Aggregate' projection is only needed when it is necessary to display  unique segment ids (say, with the latest revision).